# What is the name for the transformation of "good on you" to "onya"?

Tags: word-formation, clipping

In Australian slang, there is a word "Onya" which is used in the exact same way as "Good on you".

What transformations have taken place in the formation of this slang? I'm finding it difficult to see since "Good on you" is not a single word. I think there is vowel reduction "y**ou**" -> "y**a**" (schwa phoneme). But what else is there, elision, shortening?

Comment: Certainly it's a shortening; I don't think it's exactly an elision, since the word _good_ is dropped completely rather than elided. You could also call it a _corruption_ - 'the process by which a word or expression is changed from its original state to one regarded as erroneous or debased.'

Comment: Possibly as near an answer as one will get, possibly a duplicate: [Are kinda/sorta/oughta and sposta acceptable in formal writing?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162280/are-kinda-sorta-oughta-and-sposta-acceptable-in-formal-writing).

Comment: This is a form of apheresis where it is affecting a phrase rather than a word. I'm uncertain whether it has a name or not. But it's why we say "thank you" in place of "I thank you" and the like.

Comment: In the US, the phrase _good on you_ exists, but it's stressed on _good_ and _you_ In Oz, the stressed syllable is _on_, with _good_ reduced to /gd/ before _on_, Naturally the initial unpronounceable stops disappear.

Comment: It's East London UK slang for _good on you_.

Comment: Good on you. [good] onya where you become ya.

Answer (score 1):

The grammatical dropping of complete words from a phrase is known as:

> [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

Sometimes the plainer term 'deletion' is used.

(Elision and syncope and apocope and etc are used for phonological dropping of sounds).